ConnectWise and Smartsheet Integration using Power Automate
I want to pull in projects from ConnectWise to Smartsheet and want to set them so whenever updates have been made to them it reflects in SmartSheet automatically. All this is to be achieved using Power Automate.
Since Power automate does not have ConnectWise functions, I had to use the http method which would basically use api to fetch the data. This worked but it is not showing all fields in Smartsheet.
Additionally it won't update the data automatically in SmartSheet.
